# Conditional loading of items in a viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs

hello,
to manage user access,i need to disable loading some items, in a viewport for now i hide them with a the "hidden" property, but I can't prevent the background processing for this items, such as the server request

how can i disable loading for a specific items.

this my viewport code

```
var notAllowAdmin=true; //init access rule gere for admin panel

Ext.define('eFinances.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
requires: [
    'Ext.layout.container.Border'
],

layout: 'border',

items: [
    {
        xtype: 'eFinancesToolbar',
        region: 'north'
    },
    {

       title: 'Navigation',
       region: 'west',
       collapsible: true,
       split: true,
       width: 200,
       minWidth: 175,
       maxWidth: 400,
       animCollapse: true,
       margins: '0 0 0 5',
       layout: 'accordion',
       items: [{
              xtype:'menuTresorerie',
              title: 'Trésoreries',
              iconCls: 'balance' // see the HEAD section for style used


            },{

              xtype:'menuAchat',
              title: 'Achat et fournisseurs',
              iconCls: 'depense' // see the HEAD section for style used

            }, {
              xtype:'menuVente',
              title: 'Ventes et clients',
              iconCls: 'recette'
            }, {
              xtype:'menuAdmin',
              hidden :notAllowAdmin, // hide items if not allowed
              title: 'Administration',
              iconCls: 'administration'

            }]

    },
    {
        region: 'center',
        title: 'work area'
    }
 ]

});
```

for the moment i hide admin panel with notAllowAdmin variable initialized with rules access , but whole background process are executed, some can tell me how to proceed to completly disactivate panel loading or give me best idea to do this (managing users access)

regards

Comment: Hiding this client side is not a safe method for preventing server side functionality, and server side requests. You should create a proper user access permissioning set-up to ensure users can't perform server side queries for which they lack permissions.

Comment: you can put flags for the speicific users with respect to the flag you can show or hide the items.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I've done server side controls, but I would like optimize my application to avoid to load éléments for which the user does not have access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop adding hidden components to the items array. Example:

```
items: [
    {
        xtype:'menuTresorerie',
        title: 'Trésoreries',
        iconCls: 'balance' // see the HEAD section for style used
    },
    {
        xtype:'menuAchat',
        title: 'Achat et fournisseurs',
        iconCls: 'depense' // see the HEAD section for style used
    },
    {
        xtype:'menuVente',
        title: 'Ventes et clients',
        iconCls: 'recette'
    }
].concat(notAllowAdmin ? [] : [
    {
      xtype:'menuAdmin',
      title: 'Administration',
      iconCls: 'administration'
    }
]);
```

But you should notice that this should be trated only as optimization, and true access control should be implemented on server side.